# Websocket connection does not read complete data

Tags: java, android, websocket, java-websocket

I am using [java-websocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) library on `android` client side for communicating with `python` ws server. I am using above library to handle asynchronous response from server. The following are the `@override` methods of `websocket` class:

```
 @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message)
    {

    }

    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteBuffer byteBuffer)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ByteBuffer bytes)
    {
        super.onMessage(bytes);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e)
    {
    }
```

When `android-client` got asynchronous response from server in string format and if it exceeds over 4096 bytes, then `onMessage(String)` get incomplete data. While server sends complete data. I have tested it for around 8000 bytes.
How could `android-client` read all data(more than 4096 bytes) in `websocket` stream ? Does anyone have face problem like this using [java-websocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) library?

Comment: How often is onMessage() invoked when the server sends more data? Several times i think.

Comment: For each response `onMessage()` invoked one time

Comment: Are you checking all three onMessage()'s?

Comment: Yes, I have check all three messages. In that case only string parameter `onMessage()` call

Comment: Sorry, i dont know a solution.

Comment: Problem solved. I made mistake to read complete data. Now it reads all stuff. [This] (https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) library works fine.